# OTRS 6: Errors flooding log file when daylight saving time showed up

Tags: timezone, otrs, daylight-saving

I've got serious issue with otrs 6.

Everything was working fine since yesterday, but today in my timezone we started daylight time saving (added one hour)

And Log was flooded with Errors like this:

[Sun Mar 28 19:36:30 2021][Error][Kernel::System::DateTime::new][154] Error creating DateTime object.

And

OTRS-otrs.Daemon.pl - Daemon Kernel::System::Daemon::DaemonModules::SchedulerCronTaskManager-10     Error creating DateTime object.
in GUI/WebUI

TimeZone is ok in OTRSTimeZone and it's ok in OS.
When I change OTRSTimeZone to UTC errors dissapear, but I've got messed up hours in tickets ;/

I've seen some topics about this issue, but nothing is working for me ;/

https://community.znuny.org/viewtopic.php?p=161559
https://community.znuny.org/viewtopic.php?f=62&t=41582&p=171775#p171775

Anyone knows what to do with that issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem maybe not solved, but discovered.
It happens only in days with time change. So it will flood your log with errors but only until that day ends. After midnight everything is going back to proper work.